# Session destroyed after redirect in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

the issue i am facing is when i redirect to some page my session got destroyed. i am facing this issue in live server only and working flawlessly in localhost. this issue was not there few months ago on different hosting company

here is my session configuration

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

Comment: please compare and add CI and php version of localhost and production to the question

Comment: It's a good idea to hard-code the `sess_save_path` path. Also make sure to chmod 700 for the directory, see under 'Files driver' at https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: can you tell me what to hardcode?

Comment: Have you read the link? You should add an absolute path to the sessions directory you want, and it should be a non public directory. The suggestion is `/application/sessions` or equal depending on your environment. Then chmod it. Most probably the reason your sessions dont get stored on your new server is that CI can't save/read the session files. Another suggestion is using a database or memcached if you have, i'ts faster.

Comment: some OS works fine with $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL like centOS while other server need path to store session. provide session path then check

Answer (score 0):

You are using the "files" driver so you must supply a path to `$config['sess_save_path']`.  You set the value to NULL which will not work.

The value assigned to `$config['sess_save_path']` must be a full, absolute, path and must have the appropriate owner and permission settings. Documentation on the [files driver](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver).

For reasons of security, many devs create a folder on the same level as the website public folder. If that folder is named "sessions" then you could set the config like this

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = dirname(FCPATH .'/sessions/');
```

The other thing to try is being explicit with the cookie_domain, ie.

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = '.yourdomain.tld';
```

Be sure to include the leading dot.

Comment: tried this but nothing happens after that i tried using database the entries are there but session is still getting destroyed

Comment: Added something else to try.